# How to write to serial ports that are connected to eachother

Tags: serial-port

I have a serial port connected to the back of the computer, and a usb --> serial port connected as well.

The port is accessed through ttyS0, and the usb through ttyUSB/ I have then connected them together, by taking 2 female ends, and soldering the wires together, forming an adapter, making sure that line 2(RX) is connected to line 3(TX) and line 5(reference) is the same.

In theory I think this should work as a type of loop back, so when using software such as CuteCom or Serial port Terminal, if I send "A", the character "A" should be returned as if I had just used a loopback directly on the back of the pc. At the moment I get no response though. Should I be trying to send through ttyS0, or ttyUSB0?

Thanks in advance for any help, Ed

Comment: This question might be better served on Super User and not Stack Overflow

Comment: Your description is a bit vague, but you do need to setup two (2) instances of CuteCom or minicom, one for **/dev/ttyS0** and *another* for **/dev/ttyUSB0**.  What you type in one terminal emulator should then show up in the other.  Whether you get an echo when you type will depend on the setup of both terminal emulators (i.e. local and/or remote echo settings).

Comment: wow, great answer, worked first time! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In theory I think this should work as a type of loop back

Actually, no.  With only one terminal emulator program on one serial port, whatever you type will end up in the bit bucket on the other end.

A proper loopback directs the output of a device back into the input side of the (same) device.
But you have two devices, i.e. two serial ports that happen to reside in the same PC instead of different PCs.
What you enter at Port A is transmitted to the input side of Port B.
To receive something at Port A you would have to send it from Port B.
Since you only have a terminal emulator on Port A and nothing for Port B, you will see no activity with your setup.
Since Port A and Port B are independent devices, you have to setup terminal emulators in the same manner as if there were on two different PCs.

You need to setup two (2) instances of *CuteCom* or *minicom*, one for **/dev/ttyS0** and another for **/dev/ttyUSB0**.
What you type in one terminal emulator should then show up in the other.

Whether you get an echo when you type will depend on the setup of both terminal emulators (i.e. local and/or remote echo settings).  You can configure (or misconfigure) the terminal emulators so that you could see no echo at all, or one echo (from either the local or the remote side), or a double echo (an echo from both local and remote side).